# How to give priority to IPv6 Address Record (AAAA) on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, dns, ipv6, osx-mountain-lion

When a site has both AAAA record and A record,

If using Lion, connected to the server of the AAAA record.
However, if Mountain Lion, connected to the server of the A record.

Example:
http://www.kame.net/

Lion : Kame is dancing.
Windows 7 : Kame is dancing.
Mountain Lion : Kame is NOT dancing.

Is there the method to give priority to AAAA record in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS Lion and Mountain Lion base their choice between IPv4 and IPv6 on latency measurements. The idea is that the system chooses what is best for the user, but the downside is that it is almost completely unpredictable whether IPv4 or IPv6 will be used for a connection. I don't think there is a way to change that behaviour.

Comment: Meaning, latency on the resolved host or the time it takes for the IPv4/IPv6 DNS answer to come back?

Comment: Latency of the resolved host addresses, or if they are not known the average latency of all IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.